# How to perform SQL query using Popel ORM in Symfony

Tags: sql, orm, symfony1, propel

Here is my problem,
i'm trying to do tag cloud in symfony, what i want to perform is such a sql query

select tag, count(tag) from tagi group by tag order by count(tag) desc limit 10

anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Create a function in the Peer (not the BasePeer) class that maps to your "tag" table.  Example:

```
public static function doGetTags() {

    $connection = Propel::getConnection();
    // get the query from configuration
    $query = sfConfig::get('app_query_tags_all');
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = self::populateObjects($statement);
}
```